# Unable to connect to hbase from java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have set up local hbase and everything is working fine on hbase shell. On running the status command i can see the following output.

```
1 active master, 0 backup masters, 1 servers, 0 dead, 3.0000 average load
```

However when i try to run the following lines in java -

```
Configuration hBaseConfiguration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
hBaseConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
hBaseConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
hBaseConfiguration.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase");
HBaseAdmin.available(hBaseConfiguration);
```

It gives me the exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1.exec(ReadOnlyZKClient.java:189)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient.run(ReadOnlyZKClient.java:323)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can you give me any help regarding this?

Comment: can you do a **telnet localhost 2181** just to check whether connection is getting established?

Comment: Getting this output: Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: can you try forcing the client to use IPv4? -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true may be zooker is not listening on IPv6 localhost ::1

Comment: Getting the same error

Comment: you code looks fine. use the same details which is present in hbase master UI.  http://master:16010/   under "Zookeeper Quorum"